# Show base64 image next to canvas with charts.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, base64, chart.js

I'm using charts.js which has an option to add an attribute containing a base64 image of the canvas, like this:

```
animation: {
    onComplete: function(animation){
        document.querySelector('#myChart').setAttribute('href', this.toBase64Image());
    }
},
```

Here is the full working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0on3f7t7/

When you inspect the canvas you can see a href attribute containing the image, so that works. But instead I need to display the image below the canvas. So, yes, there will be two charts on the screen, the canvas version and the image version.

I can't find an answer to this question anyway, and the documentation doesn't give any clues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add an `<img>` element to your page, and then set the `src` attribute of the `<img>` element to the output of `this.toBase64Image()`

See the following fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/wveepa7c/

```
onComplete: function(animation){
  // #myImage is an img element
  document.querySelector('#myImage').setAttribute('src', this.toBase64Image());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`onComplete` is called at least two times at jsfiddle. You can define a variable which is `undefined`, at `onComplete` check if variable is defined to prevent `<img>` being appended to `document` twice, if variable is not defined, create `<img>` element, use `.insertAdjacentHTML()` chained to `ctx` with first parameter `"afterend"` and second parameter `.outerHTML` of `<img>` element

```
var img;
```

```
animation: {
  onComplete: function(animation) {
    if (!img) {
      ctx.setAttribute('href', this.toBase64Image());
      img = new Image;
      img.src = ctx.getAttribute('href');
      ctx.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", img.outerHTML)
    }
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0on3f7t7/2/